# How can I get A List Of contacts A user chat with in Appolozic?

Tags: java, chat, applozic

Folks,

I am trying out my hand on Applozic since Yesterday. I find it awesome but a problem about How to get the Contact list for a Particular user?

What I mean to say that,

Suppose I am user A and I chat with B, C, D and E. I want to show the chat user list containing the name of B,C,D and E. I don't want the groups.

I checked out this link,
[how to list out my contact list and send message in applozic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371441/how-to-list-out-my-contact-list-and-send-message-in-applozic)

and, 
[How to get list of my users in AppLozic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665300/how-to-get-list-of-my-users-in-applozic)

But, I am not getting it . Actually I want the list like the screenshot given on your github page,
[image]

I followed this link and added users,
https://docs.applozic.com/docs/android-contacts
but not getting the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That screen which is attached its for  conversation screen you will see users there only when you had a conversation with any users

To start the conversation with user there are two ways

1) Follow this doc [link](https://docs.applozic.com/docs/android-chat-theme-and-customization#section-applozic-settings-json-properites-detail) for adding the applozic-settings.json file for enabling the contacts on click of plus button it will show the all registered contacts in applozic 

 `"registeredUserContactListCall": true,`

2) Insert your own contacts from your server by using applozic contacts api methods this is the doc for contacts api
[link](https://docs.applozic.com/docs/android-contacts) and the sample code [link](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/applozic/mobicomkit/sample/LoginActivity.java#L351) for contacts inserting into applozic local data base

Comment: Hi, Thanks For Your reply. Actually, I already used the 2nd part, I mean I got it from the link You provided only. But, I am not getting the list of users and every time I need to login, Single sign in is not happen, Can You please give me idea about why its happening? I will accept the answer once the problem is solved. Thanks Again

Comment: Is there any specific activity which I can navigate to show the above screen I uploaded? Like for conversation we start ConversationActivity.

Comment: the above screen is ConversationActivity not contacts screen for contacts screen opening you need to click + plus button

Comment: Thank You .  I got it. But, I don't want to show the GROUPS. Conversation activity is showing all the contacts and groups. I am not sure when I created the groups? Could You please help?

Comment: for disabling group completely add applzoic-settings.json file from this doc https://docs.applozic.com/docs/android-chat-theme-and-customization  then make   "startNewGroup": false,